# I accidentally set password to blank for a PostgreSQL database, how do I change it?

Tags: postgresql

When I set the password to blank, it didn't give any warnings. Now when I try to log in with a blank password, it gives me an error "fe_sendauth: no password supplied". So now I can't log in - any ideas how I can get access to the db again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on how your cluster is configured...

If you have another administrator user (postgres?) you can just connect and:

`ALTER USER username PASSWORD 'new password';`

Otherwise you could (temporarily) allow password-less logins in `pg_hba.conf` (see  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html - search for the word "trust")

Comment: I just edited giorgiga's post to remove UNENCRYPTED.  There is an obvious confusion here, that folks might think it refers to the password supplied in the argument, but in fact it refers to storage.  I seem to recall a few very unusual corner cases where it might be appropriate but it is *definitely* not a good blanket recommendation unless you know very clearly that you need it and why.

Answer (score 11):

This [blogpost](http://www.depesz.com/2008/11/28/recovering-lost-postgresql-password/) should answer. Full disclosure: it's my blogpost.

Summary:

> If you have access to shell account on the machine PostgreSQL is running, and your shell works as the same user as Postgres itself, or root – solution is easy.
>
> Edit your `pg_hba.conf` file, and at the beginning of it put:
>
> `local all all trust`
>
> or (depending on your paranoia):
>
> `local all postgres ident`
>
> And restart your PostgreSQL (usually something like /etc/init.d/postgres restart).
>
> Afterwards you should be able to connect to Postgres as postgres user without password.
>
> You should note, that if you have choosen the option with “ident” you will be able to connect without password only from shell account named “postgres”.
>
> don't forget to reverse the `pg_hba.conf` settings when you have reset the password.

Comment: Sorry for the fuss depesz, I hope you don't mind my summary of your blog post. You are a special user and deserve special treatment but some from outside the postgres world on this site don't know that :)

Comment: No problem at all. I definitely do not feel special, I'm just not in favor of adding yet-another (after all google/bing/whatever caches) copy of the same information. But if someone (like you in this case) wants to add it - I have no problem with it.