# How do I either set a password for postgres, properly use the postgres user, or stop postgres from asking me for a password?

Tags: postgresql

I am fairly new to programming, and I am using postgres 12.2.

I am having a lot of trouble even setting up postgres. When I try to connect to a database, such as using

psql -U postgres -d demo

which is the first command in the list of commands [here](https://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Basic-and-Useful-PostgreSQL-Commands/), I get prompted for a password, which I have never set.

As far as I can tell, postgres should be a "super-user" that does not have a password. Through using resources online, I have used the command initdb to make an initial database cluster (though I do not know how to use this cluster) and I have set the bin file to be in the path system variable, something which I do not understand the purpose of.

Here is an example:

```
C:\>psql -U postgres -d C:\usr\local\pgsql\data\base\1
```

Password for user postgres:
psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Comment: You don't really want a superuser to not have a password, do you?

Comment: May be [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34323/i-accidentally-set-password-to-blank-for-a-postgresql-database-how-do-i-change) can help

Comment: How did you install the software?

Comment: "*which I have never set*" - yes you have. The Windows installer **does** ask you for one (and you have to provide one when running initdb). But the installer already runs initdb for you, there is no need to create a second cluster. And you need to provide the name of the database for `psql` not the path to the cluster. Every default installation has a database name `postgres` so you would need `-d postgres`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you're right, I deleted my installed copy of postgres and reinstalled it, and then I could set a new password. Thanks, I feel dumb now haha.